# From (n,) to (n,1) numpy arrays and viceversa?

Tags: python, numpy

I understand that Numpy treats arrays with shapes `(n,1)` differently from those with `(n,)` shapes, although they can hold the same data.

How can I convert between them?

Comment: Why the downvote? Is the question not clear? If so, how can I improve it?

Comment: May have just been downvoted before the edit fixing your typo, but adding a bit of code to show what you are referring to would improve the quality.

Answer (score 6):

Hopefully the following should illustrate the difference, with `(n,)` you have a flat array, with `(n,1)` you have a nested array (array of `n` one-element arrays):

```
>>> np.ones(10).reshape((10,))
array([ 1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.,  1.])
>>> np.ones(10).reshape((10,1))
array([[ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.]])
```

Answer (score 4):

An easy way to add an axis of length one is to index with `np.newaxis`:

```
In [188]: a = np.arange(10)

In [189]: a
Out[189]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9])

In [190]: a[:, np.newaxis]
Out[190]: 
array([[0],
       [1],
       [2],
       [3],
       [4],
       [5],
       [6],
       [7],
       [8],
       [9]])

In [191]: a[np.newaxis, :]
Out[191]: array([[0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9]])
```

You can actually just use `None` instead: `a[:, None]`.

An easy way to get rid of all length-one axes is to use `np.squeeze`:

```
In [193]: a = np.ones((2,1,3))

In [194]: a
Out[194]: 
array([[[ 1.,  1.,  1.]],

       [[ 1.,  1.,  1.]]])

In [195]: a.squeeze()
Out[195]: 
array([[ 1.,  1.,  1.],
       [ 1.,  1.,  1.]])
```

Another way to remove it is simply to just slice that one axis:

```
In [197]: a = np.ones((3,1))

In [198]: a
Out[198]: 
array([[ 1.],
       [ 1.],
       [ 1.]])

In [199]: a[:, 0]
Out[199]: array([ 1.,  1.,  1.])
```

Answer (score 0):

```
In [12]: import numpy as np                                                     

In [13]: a=np.arange(1, 11)                                                     

In [14]: a                                                                      
Out[14]: array([ 1,  2,  3,  4,  5,  6,  7,  8,  9, 10])

In [15]: a.shape                                                                
Out[15]: (10,)

In [16]: b=np.expand_dims(a, axis=1)                                            

In [17]: b                                                                      
Out[17]: 
array([[ 1],
       [ 2],
       [ 3],
       [ 4],
       [ 5],
       [ 6],
       [ 7],
       [ 8],
       [ 9],
       [10]])

In [18]: b.shape                                                                
Out[18]: (10, 1)
```